# Python Package - "No module named" error when importing from its own subpackage

Tags: python, package

I have a Python package called **test_package**, where I am trying to import a class from **constants.py** into **main.py**.

When I try to import test_package.main, I get "no module named 'classes'" error even though it's right there. What am I doing wrong?

In the terminal, I am in the directory one level above test-package.

```
$ python
Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test_package.main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\<my username>\Documents\PythonProjects\test_package\main.py", line 1, i
n <module>
    from classes.constants import Constants
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classes'
>>> exit()
```

Project Structure

```
test_package
|   __init__.py
|   main.py
|
+---classes
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   constants.py
```

constants.py:

```
class Constants:
    ONE = "one"
    TWO = "two"
    THREE = "three"
```

main.py:

```
from classes.constants import Constants

def print_message():
    print(Constants.ONE)
```

Comment: can you share full project structure

Comment: You need to run the main.py directly instead of running `test_package.main`.
If you want to run it through `test_package`, you need to use relative imports
so it would be `from .classes.constants import Constants`

Comment: @sahasrara62 That is the full project structure, just the basics to test the imports

Comment: @Ryuga Thank you, that essentially resolved my import problems in the code. For running main.py directly, do you mean `python main.py`? or something like `import test_package.main as main`?